# Cordova InAppBrowser _self not executing watchposition code

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I am trying to open my website in `cordova` app using `InAppBrowser` and with following code

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,'_self','location=no');
```

It works fine and the website is loaded fine but I also need the accurate user location and I am using `geoLocation` plugin to get the position with following code

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(watchPosition, onError, options);
```

Once the `InAppBrowser` code is executed, `watchPosition` doesnt execute anymore.

If I use `_blank` instead of `_self` everything works fine.

Is there a work around to this?

following is my code

```
onDeviceReady: function() {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(watchSuccess, onError, options);

    sendData('https://testdomain.com');
}
```

Following are the functions

```
function sendData(url){

    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(watchPosition, onError, options);

    $.post({
        url: "https://testdomain.com/mobileInfo",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({"latitude":Latitude,"device":device}),
        success: function () {
            console.log("Device data sent");
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,'_self','location=no');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error){
            console.log("Device data not sent with error");
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,'_self','location=no');
        }
    });
}

function onError(error) {
    console.log('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

function watchSuccess(position) {
    Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}

function watchPosition(position) {

    var updatedLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var updatedLongitude = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log("watching position");

    if (updatedLatitude !== Latitude && updatedLongitude !== Longitude) {

        Latitude = updatedLatitude;
        Longitude = updatedLongitude;

        console.log("position changed");

        $.post({
            url: "https://testdomain.com/mobileInfo",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({"latitude":Latitude,"device":device}),
            success: function () {
                console.log("Device position changed and sent to server");

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/:

**_self:** Opens in the Cordova WebView **if the URL is in the white list**, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.

**_blank:** Opens in the InAppBrowser.

Comment: I have no problem opening up the url. After the view is loaded, `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` stops working. It does not fetch the changed location

Comment: did you try to remove the url in the white list ?

Comment: remove it from whitelist or add it in whitelist??

Comment: i know it sound weird, but the doc said to remove the url to open it in inappbrowser if using _self.